# Jenkins Sonarqube Plugin: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, java-home

I am trying to set up the Sonarqube for my project, but when I start to generate a build, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home
   folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there.

The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
```

I check some docs but none of them helps. For the JAVA_HOME environment variable, I point it to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111` I also double check it by using powershell `java -version` command. It also gives me the same answer: `java version "1.8.0_111"` . Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that java,exe exists? Did you check the access rights?

Answer (score 3):

You can edit:

`C:\Users\HOME_FOLDER\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonarQubeScanner\bin>notepad sonar-scanner.bat`

and put following:

`SET JAVA_HOME=< JDK Path>`

Answer (score 1):

`if EXIST` in the sonar-scanner.bat fails because there is a space in the path, so the solution is to set the JAVA_HOME to a value without spaces e.g. using the short name of the "Program Files" `SET JAVA_HOME= C:\Progra~1\Java\jre9`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. The issue was with sonar-scanner.bat referencing wrong %JAVA_HOME% path.
In the sonar-scanner.bat the variable "use_embedded_jre" is set to true and immediately the validation is done for the PATH.

```
@REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
@REM *** JAVA EXEC VALIDATION ***

set use_embedded_jre=true
if "%use_embedded_jre%" == "true" (
  set "JAVA_HOME=%SONAR_SCANNER_HOME%\jre"
)
```

Set the variable value to "false", the issue will be fixed.

```
set use_embedded_jre=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that JAVA_HOME is pointing JDK .

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reinstall the java 8. Setup JAVA_HOME again then It will work.
This problem might be because space between "Program Files (x86)"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and struggled with it for a while.
After modifying `sonar-scanner.bat` a bit I found out that during execution of Sonarqube the `%JAVA_HOME%` was completely different from the one I configured in my environment variables.
Turned out I had hardcoded `JDK installations` in my `Global Tool Configuration` inside Jenkins.

My solution:

1. Open your Jenkins, go to `Manage Jenkins` -> `Global Tool Configuration`
2. Click `JDK installations...`
3. Make sure `JAVA_HOME` parameter is empty or just click `Delete JDK`

In this case Jenkins will use `%JAVA_HOME%` variable it finds during the execution and it's just the one you configured in your environment variables. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You should restart your machine after java installation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. On my machine JRE was located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre`. So I appended System's PATH Environment Variable with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin;`

It worked.

Do not forget to restart Jenkins service from Windows Services